# Find substring within a string ignoring white spaces in perl

Tags: regex, perl, substring, string-matching

`String 1: quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog`

`String 2: jumps     over    a lazy`

i will pass these strings to a subroutine which returns boolean value.

My present solution is to remove spaces from both the strings and pattern match .

Is there a better solution .

Comment: Remove spaces and use index()

Comment: Can you also search for `quick jumps lazy`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing the whitespace would match

> ju mps over a laz y

in

> quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog

But I assume, that this is not what you want. So, it would be a good idea to convert the whitespace to patterns before you try to match:

```
sub substr_ignore_whitespace
{
    my $string      = shift;
    my $sub_string  = shift;

    $sub_string =~ s/\s+/\\s+/g;

    return $string =~ /$sub_string/;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to *normalize* the input so that a direct comparison can take place. Here, we could replace all sequences of white space characters by a single space.

```
sub fuzzy_contains {
    my ($haystack, $needle) = @_;
    # fold the spaces
    s/\s+/ /g for $haystack, $needle;
    return -1 < index $haystack, $needle;
}
```

You may want to apply further normalizations, such as case-folding the strings for case independent matching (use `fc` from [Unicode::CaseFold](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unicode::CaseFold) or from [`feature 'fc'`](http://perldoc.perl.org/feature.html#The-'fc'-feature)).

Comment: Didnt know about case fold, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest this approach:

In the needle string using this search and replace:

```
's/ +/ .*?/g'
```

Which is basically replacing each space by `.*?` (space followed by 0 or more any character) this will give you:

```
jumps .*?over .*?a .*?lazy
```

Then you can do regex match between your string data and needle.

Comment: Cool this  is more than what i asked for , It matches across words .

Comment: Yes that was the reason I asked the question in comment since my answer catered to matching across the words.

Answer (score 0):

```
...
my $str1 = "quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog";
$str1 =~ s|\s+||g;

my $substr = "jumps over a lazy";
$substr =~ s|\s+||g;

my $result = index($str1, $substr);
...
```